# Set cookies on generated axis2 client

Tags: web-services, cookies, sharepoint, apache-axis

I do not find a method to set options to my generated axis2 client code. I created classes using wsimport tool and have the following "main" method here:

```
URL wsdlURL = new URL( "https://apiomat-my.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL" );
Lists service = new Lists( wsdlURL, new QName( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", "Lists" ) );
ListsSoap port = service.getListsSoap( );
```

Lists is generated and extends *Service*, while ListsSoap is an interface. Every example I found talks about setting options to a stub, but I do not have any class ending with "Stub" nor implementing such one.

Any hints?